# Only valid managed objects can be copied from Realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I have one-to-many relationship in Realm

```
public class BayEntity extends RealmObject implements RealmModel {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int     id;
    private String  title;
}

public class TermEntity extends RealmObject implements RealmModel {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String termId;
    private String name;

    private RealmList<BayEntity> bayList;

 public void updateBayList(ArrayList<BayEntity> bayList) {

        if(CollectionUtility.isEmptyOrNull(this.bayList))
            this.bayList = new RealmList();
        this.bayList.addAll(bayList);
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealm(this.bayList);
        realm.insertOrUpdate(this); //update current instance
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }

    public ArrayList<BayEntity> getSimpleList() {
        if(CollectionUtility.isEmptyOrNull(bayList))
            return new ArrayList<>();
        return (ArrayList<BayEntity>) realm.copyFromRealm(bayList);
    }
}
```

I am getting all `TermEntity` objects containing baylist as:

```
public RealmResults<TermEntity> getTerms() {
        return realm.where(TermEntity.class).findAll();
    }
```

I am able to save and retrieve `bayList` successfully. When I try to convert it into `Arraylist` in method `getSimpleList()`, I am getting exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only valid managed objects can be
>   copied from Realm.

I can't understand how objects can be unmanaged when they are saved and retrieved from realm. Please correct me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me as though you have several problems:

1. Where are you getting the `Realm` instance that you use in the `updateBayList` method?  Since it is instance local state, it might easily refer to a Realm that is not valid in the current context (time or thread)
2. The first three lines `if ... addAll(bayList);` modify `Term`s `RealmList`.  You can't do that outside of a transaction, if the object is managed.  When the object is *not* managed, you get the error you describe, because you are trying to add managed objects to an unmanaged `RealmList`
3. While not a problem, `RealmObject` already implements `RealmModel`.  Say something once, why say it again?

**Edited to add:**

In order to add `BayEntity`s to a `TermEntity`, first make sure that the `TermEntity` is a managed object (use `copyToRealm`, or query for it). Once you do that, the code in `updateBayList` is very nearly correct.  You want something like:

```
    realm.beginTransaction();
    if (CollectionUtility.isEmptyOrNull(this.bayList)) {
        this.bayList = new RealmList();
    }
    this.bayList.addAll(bayList);
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out mistakes in my code. Can you please kindly tell me correct way of updating bayList? I want to add items to already existing list.. Thanks

Comment: Moreover, realm is an instance from a singleton class, managed separately. I have mentioned like this here for simplicity.